# How to get bot's role color? Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to match bot's embed color and it's role color. So far I found only this solution, but instead of a user's role color I want bot's color:

```
.setColor(message.member.displayHexColor)
```

I was trying to target the bot with `message.author.bot` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: First of all `.bot` is a boolean property meaning it's either true or false (if the account is a bot). Secondly, are you testing this in a DM? In a DM, the Message object will have no guild or member properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `message.guild.me.displayHexColor` is what you are looking for.
 `guild.me` returns bot user as a member of a current guild.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a bot is also a 'user' but at the very least a member of the server; context is important here.
Do you pick a member specifically or only when they do a command?
If it's the former, you can try the same thing you did with

`.setColor(message.member.displayHexColor)`

but choose the bot as member instead